Can't install Ubuntu 24LTS installed on Dell Inspiron 3891
Created boot file with Belena_Etcher. Known good - installed Ubuntu on backup machine first. No problem.  Dell Gets to boot menu, but locks as soon as option chosen. Tried turning off Secure boot, changing various other BIOS settings, and waiting quarter hour after each lock up to confirm that system was truly locked. No joy. (Note: Used USB stick on laptop after Dell failure. Worked fine.) If anyone knows a work-around I'd appreciate the help.  --Thanks

There is no such version of Ubuntu as 24LTS Ubuntu 24 would be a version of Ubuntu Core Please edit the question and give the accurate version info. As soon as what option chosen. Please also edit the question and add some details.Changing various settings does not say what you have done. An answer or possible answer is only as good as the info supplied.

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you tried with TPM off in bios?
